# ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (SQLite3::ReadOnlyException: when using postgres

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, sqlite, web-deployment, digital-ocean

I am trying to deploy my first rails application on digital ocean in Ubuntu, I am unsure if I am doing this right.  I initially had my production database in postgres and test and production in sqllite.  In frustration, I changed all my databases to postgres my changing the database.yml.  I am unsure if I did that correctly  But I had this error:  ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (SQLite3::ReadOnlyException: .  When I was in sqllite.  I was not sure if I had to tell the server to switch to production mode or if it was configured to use sqllite.

What I want to do is use postgres instead of sqllite.  I am using nginx and Unicorn.  MY database is blank so I dont need to transfer anything.  I have made the postgres database within postgres,  I just need to point my app to that database.  (I am unaware if I need to do something else

I have used this database.yml

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  host: localhost
  database: blog_development
  pool: 5
  username: bob
  password: password

test:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: blog_test
  host: localhost
  pool: 5
  username: bob
  password: password

production:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  host: localhost
  database: blog_production
  pool: 5
  username: bob
  password: password
```

Gem file:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.0.0'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.1.4'

# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.3'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
gem 'therubyracer',  platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'

gem 'jquery-ui-rails'

# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0',          group: :doc

# Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
gem 'spring',        group: :development

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

# Use debugger
# gem 'debugger', group: [:development, :test]

gem 'bootstrap-sass' # for using bootstrap-rails"

gem 'faker'

gem 'will_paginate'

gem 'annotate', '~> 2.6.5'

gem 'font-awesome-rails' # for using font-awesome icons

gem 'redcarpet', '~> 2.1.1'
gem 'coderay', '~> 1.1.0' # For nice code snippets


gem 'devise'

gem 'sidekiq'

gem 'haml-rails'

group :development do
  gem 'better_errors'
  gem 'binding_of_caller'
  gem 'meta_request'
  gem 'guard-rspec'
end

group :test do
  gem 'capybara'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails', '4.2.0'
end

gem 'pg', '0.15.1'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  # Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record in testing
end

group :production do

  gem 'rails_12factor', '0.0.2'
end
```

I have the rest of the code on my github:  https://github.com/RubyQuarry/Bootstrap_blog

Comment: Under what circumstances are you getting that error?  When you try to start the console?  Run the server?

Comment: This is happening when I try to write to the application (make a comment) at: http://104.236.51.180/blogs/10

Comment: Can you run `rake db:drop db:create db:migrate`?  Can you log into the Rails console and create a Comment object through that interface?  If not, what is the error?

Comment: Did you restart everything after changing databases? Sounds like your application still thinks it is talking to SQLite.

Comment: I got it working through running, rake db:drop db:create db:migrate thank you @Bryce

Comment: I'll add that as an answer, and you can accept it then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run `rake db:drop db:create db:drop` to drop your old database(s) and recreate the new ones in Postgres.